# Getting NullPointerException when mail having .msg attachment

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, exchangewebservices

I am very new to stack overflow to post my question. 
I am writing a program to read mails from EWS which is having attachments. When any mail is having mail(.msg) as attachment program is failing by saying NullPointerException.

Below is the code snippet i am using.

```
service.loadPropertiesForItems(results, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));
PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients);
itItemId = new ItemId(emailItem.getId().toString());
emEmailMessage = EmailMessage.bind(service, itItemId, psPropSet);
AttachmentCollection attachments = emailItem.getAttachments();
attachments.forEach((attachment) -> { }
```

Can any one pls suggest me the answer. 
Thanks

Comment: Please post the full stack trace so we can know the exact line that is failing.

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @fpezzini Code is failing at this particular line "AttachmentCollection attachments = emailItem.getAttachments();". and leads to exception.

Comment: Ok, in that case there's a very good chance that emailItem is null. This means that the call EmailMessage.bind(service, itItemId, psPropSet) returned null.
Are you using https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/service/item/EmailMessage.java ? 
I'd recommend you place a break point and try to step through that code now to figure out the exact point where a variable is null. Generally speaking a NullPointerException means an invalid state of the application, some assumption is no longer valid.

Comment: @fpezzini Thanks for reply. But i could able to load the pdf , image files other than (.msg) email attachment. EmailMessage.bind(service, itItemId, psPropSet) is working fine for pdf , email and etc but when it encounters (.msg) email attachment in Email i am facing issue. If possible can you provide me the code snippet to ignore .msg files while loading attachments.

Comment: That's why you need to debug it. Debug it step by step with a PDF which is when it works and note down the values of the variables, then debug it again with the one that's failing to see why the variables have the values they do. See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html for more info.